# Passing values within JSP using Spring-MVC

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application. I am implementing the password reset functionality. I already can send emails, and have a password reset page. The user should just enter the password, the token will be checked and password reset. I am making some mistake calling the link.. I get apache error that syntax was incorrect. What am I doing wrong.

Link called for password change :

```
localhost:8085/newpassword/usernameAndDateToken
```

Controller :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/resetpassword")
    public String newPasswordPage(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("person", new Person());
        return "resetpassword";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/newpassword")
    public String changePasswordFunction(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person,@RequestParam("username")String username,Model model){
        personService.changePassword(username,person.getPassword());
        model.addAttribute("person",person);
        return "redirect:/";
    }
```

resetpassword.jsp :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<c:url var="addAction" value="/newpassword" ></c:url>
<form:form action="${addAction}" commandName="person">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form:label path="password">
                    <spring:message text="password"/>
                </form:label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <form:input path="password"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was thrown because the controller expects the url as `@RequestMapping(value = "/newpassword/{id}")` and you are sending it as `localhost:8085/newpassword/usernameAndDateToken`.

If you are trying to pass some values to the controller can pass it with the url and access it using [`@RequestParam`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html) annotation. simply as,

```
localhost:8085/newpassword/53587359878397
```

and in controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/newpassword")
    public String changePasswordFunction(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person,@PathVariable("username")String username,Model model,@RequestParam(value = "memberId") Integer memberId){

    . . . 
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, I tried what you said and changed the controller, and also in JSP used value="/newpassword", and I get error : The requested resource is not available. I am updating my post to show new JSP and controller. I have to use String, as token has characters too.